# PUBNUB operations throws PNTimeoutCategory often

Tags: ios, react-native, pubnub

I am using PubNub server in my chat app. It works fine but often I am getting `PNTimeoutCategory` error while doing PubNub operations like subscribe, unsubscribe, publish, etc. How to handle this?

```
 pubnub = new PubNub({
     authKey: auth_key,
     publishKey: publish_key,
     subscribeKey: subscribe_key,
     ssl: true,
     uuid: provider_id,
     logVerbosity: __DEV__,
 });
```

and I unsubscribe channels like below:

```
pubnub.unsubscribe({
    channels
});
```

Comment: Can you provide the result of the PubNub SDK logs? When you say "subscribe channels like below" your code shows `unsubscribe` with invalid parameter code. Perhaps some more code and context would be helpful here?

Comment: If everything is timing out, it is likely an environment issue on the client app end. Maybe bad connection or no connection? Can you check the browser console and see if there are any errors in there?

Comment: The same code works fine sometimes.

Comment: Sorry. I unsubscribe like this.

Comment: If the same code works sometimes, then you would need to capture when it doesn't work when [PubNub SDK logging is enabled](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/pubnub-javascript-sdk-troubleshooting-guide) and send log file to [PubNub Support](https://support.pubnub.com), however, it doesn't sound like it is related to PubNub (but logs would confirm this). Can you share more of your code? If you do contact PubNub Support provide your sub-key, as much code as possible (zip and attach), the log file and any errors you see in the console.

Comment: Just curious if you contacted PN Support. Are you still having issues? If you contact support, include a link to this SO post.

Comment: I contacted them. They suggest to upgrade the package. Still having issue with unsubscription. It throws timeout error still.